# Creating pub sub using go routine

Tags: go, goroutine

I am trying to create goroutine to achieve the [task](https://github.com/msa-ali/problem-solving-in-go/tree/master/task)

[image]

So I have written this code.
Task having no dependency like A,B,C are easy to implement and working fine.
Just facing some issues with implementation of dependent task D and E having dependencies of 2 tasks each.

Just one connecting dot is left which is creating a channel for each task and then passing msg which will be read by dependent task to reduce the no of dependencies if dependency task is done. see the `checkpoint 1` comment in the code.

Can anyone help me with this? I'm just stucked at this part how to implement goroutines here in this case.

code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

type task struct {
    isDone           bool
    dependencies     []*task
    subscribers      []*task
    doneChan         chan bool
    numDependencies  int
    taskName         string
    informSubChannel chan bool //
}

func (t *task) executeTask() {
    fmt.Printf("Task %s is getting executed...\n", t.taskName)
    // <-time.After(5 * time.Second)
    fmt.Printf("Task %s is done!! <-------\n", t.taskName)
}

func (t *task) updateDependency() {
    var updatedDependencies []*task
    for _, t := range t.dependencies {
        if !t.isDone {
            updatedDependencies = append(updatedDependencies, t)
        }
    }
    t.numDependencies = len(updatedDependencies)
    fmt.Printf("Updating dependency for task: %s to %d\n", t.taskName, t.numDependencies)
    t.dependencies = updatedDependencies
}

// If we are having dependencies for a task subscribe to those dependent task.
// When the dependent task is done inform it and reduce the no of dependencies.
// A --> D (D depends on A), A has finished its task so inform it subscribed task which is D here and reduce D dependencies.
func (t *task) informSubscriber() {
    if len(t.subscribers) > 0 {
        for _, sub := range t.subscribers {
            fmt.Printf("task %s has informed subscriber %s\n", t.taskName, sub.taskName)
            sub.updateDependency()
        }
    }
}

// Task is subscribed to dependent task. D has been subscribed to A, D will watch over the activity of A
func (t *task) setSubscriber(sub *task) {
    fmt.Printf("Set subscriber %s to task %s\n", sub.taskName, t.taskName)
    t.subscribers = append(t.subscribers, sub)
}

// go routine - background task execution
// mark it as completed
func (t *task) markCompleted() {
    for {
        select {
        case <-t.doneChan:
            {
                t.isDone = true
                t.executeTask()
                // inform all the subscribers that the task is completed and adjust their dependencies
                t.informSubscriber()
                close(t.doneChan)
                return
            }
        default:
        }
    }
}

func (t *task) setDependency(tasks []*task) {
    t.dependencies = tasks
    t.numDependencies = len(t.dependencies)
}

// This will be use if dependent task are already done. Will be used in checkpoint 1.
func (t *task) trackDependency() {
    t.numDependencies -= 1
    fmt.Printf("No of dependencies for task %s is: %d\n", t.taskName, t.numDependencies)
    if t.numDependencies == 0 { // execute task
        t.doneChan <- true
    }
}

func (t *task) start() {
    fmt.Printf("Running Task %s\n", t.taskName)
    t.updateDependency()
    go t.markCompleted()

    if t.numDependencies > 0 {

        // for every dependent task
        for _, dep := range t.dependencies {
            // create subscribers
            dep.setSubscriber(t)
            // what if all dependencies are already executed. Subscriber won't help as they won't be marked completed as already done.
            // say A and C are already done then D won't be able to complete itself since it's still waiting for them
            // If dependencies are already finished mark it as completed too

            // CODE: HANDLE THE DEPENDENT CASE HERE(Unable to implement)
            // background function for tracking dependency
            // CHECKPOINT 1: READ DEPENDENT TASK CHANNEL VALUE & REDUCE DEPENDENCIES IF DONE
            go t.trackDependency()
        }
        fmt.Printf("Task %s has %d dependencies and waiting for them to get finished\n", t.taskName, t.numDependencies)
    } else {
        // if no dependencies. Mark it as finished
        t.doneChan <- true
    }

}

func createTask(taskName string) *task {
    return &task{
        isDone:          false,
        taskName:        taskName,
        dependencies:    nil,
        subscribers:     nil,
        numDependencies: 0,
        doneChan:        make(chan bool),
    }
}

func main() {

    taskA := createTask("A")
    taskB := createTask("B")
    taskC := createTask("C")
    taskD := createTask("D")
    taskE := createTask("E")

    taskD.setDependency([]*task{taskA, taskB})
    taskE.setDependency([]*task{taskC, taskD})

    allTasks := []*task{taskA, taskB, taskC, taskD, taskE}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, t := range allTasks {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(t *task) {
            defer wg.Done()
            t.start()
        }(t)

    }
    wg.Wait()

}
```

**SAMPLE OUTPUT:**

```
(base) ninjakx@Kritis-MacBook-Pro Practice % go run task.go
Running Task D
Running Task B
Running Task C
Updating dependency for task: B to 0
Running Task E
Task B is getting executed...
Updating dependency for task: C to 0
Running Task A
Task C is getting executed...
Task C is done!! <-------
Updating dependency for task: D to 2
Set subscriber D to task A
Set subscriber D to task B
Task D has 2 dependencies and waiting for them to get finished
Task B is done!! <-------
No of dependencies for task D is: 2
Updating dependency for task: E to 2
Set subscriber E to task C
Set subscriber E to task D
Task E has 2 dependencies and waiting for them to get finished
No of dependencies for task E is: 2
No of dependencies for task D is: 2
No of dependencies for task E is: 2
Updating dependency for task: A to 0
task B has informed subscriber D
Updating dependency for task: D to 0
Task A is getting executed...
Task A is done!! <-------
```

currently having `Found 5 data race(s)` due to above missing implementation.

Comment: Please [don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: @tripleee That's just the problem statement which I was trying to solve via code.

Comment: Yes; what possible reason could you have to paste it as a picture instead of as text that we can copy/paste, feed to our screen readers, etc?

Comment: To highlight the main issue. Not to add more text apart from code and explanation. If you see I have added the link to the problem statement which is a text.

Comment: okay next time I will copy and paste the whole content instead of putting link and Screenshot. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve the above scenario with a smaller Task struct and some help of `WaitGroup` to synchronize.

This is an example I put together with some comments for explanation.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

// Tasks holds an id ( for ease of debugging )
// a buffered channel that is only used for signaling when the task is executed
// and finally a list of dependency tasks
type Task struct {
    id           string
    done         chan struct{}
    dependencies []*Task
}

// Run is where all the logic happens
//
// We create a WaitGroup that will be the size of the dependencies for the current Task
// and we will wait until all tasks have signaled that they have executed.
//
// When all the dependencies have signaled through their channel that they are done
// then the current task is free to execute and then signal any potential waiting Task.
func (t *Task) Run(done func()) {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(t.dependencies))

    for _, task := range t.dependencies {
        go func(dep *Task) {
            fmt.Printf("%s is waiting for task %s to finish\n", t.id, dep.id)
            <-dep.done
            wg.Done()
        }(task)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    // Emulate work
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(5-1)+1) * time.Second)

    fmt.Printf("Job %s ran\n", t.id)
    t.done <- struct{}{}
    done()
}

func NewTask(id string) *Task {
    return &Task{
        id: id,
        // We need buffered size here, else the task will be blocked until someone will read the channel on `Run`
        done: make(chan struct{}, 1),
    }
}

func (t *Task) SetDeps(deps ...*Task) {
    t.dependencies = append(t.dependencies, deps...)
}

// ExecuteTasks simply runs all the tasks concurrently and waits until every tasks is completed
func ExecuteTasks(tasks ...*Task) {
    fmt.Println("Starting execution")

    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    wg.Add(len(tasks))

    for _, task := range tasks {
        go task.Run(wg.Done)
    }

    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("End of execution")
}

func main() {
    // Initialise the tasks
    a := NewTask("a")
    b := NewTask("b")
    c := NewTask("c")
    d := NewTask("d")
    e := NewTask("e")
    // and set dependencies
    // a.SetDeps(d)
    d.SetDeps(a, b)
    e.SetDeps(d, c)

    // Then we "try" to execute all the tasks.
    ExecuteTasks(a, b, c, d, e)
}
```

Of course this is not perfect solution and I can think already a lot of cases that are not handled

e.g.

- circular dependencies will end up in deadlock `a => d` and `d => a`
- or if more than one task depend on another, the reason is that you can read the same value only once from a channel.

For solving the first issue, you would probably need to build the dependency graph and check if it's circular. And for the second one a `hacky` way could be

```golang
go func(dep *Task) {
        fmt.Printf("%s is waiting for task %s to finish\n", t.id, dep.id)
        <-dep.done
        // put the value back if anyone else is also dependent
        dep.done <- struct{}{}
        wg.Done()
}(task)
```

Comment: Also another example https://go.dev/play/p/r1g_xpleI28 instead of the hacky way you can create a more "elegant" struct called subscription and notify all "interested" tasks.

Comment: Yes If task is getting by one task channel can be used and be read once. but if the same task is getting used in multiple task then it's gonna be difficult to implement :(
I was trying to implement since yesterday. and used lot of goroutines but as you said circular dependency is the issue. With your code I am able to write this one:
https://go.dev/play/p/W1s74-CdqPr just getting stucked in dependent task. Just few logic away. I am letting one markCompleted func for each task on background.
Thanks 4 helping out. Your code is also passing the race conditions and gr8 start for me to learn. :)

Comment: If I remove `time.Sleep(time.Duration(rand.Intn(5-1)+1) * time.Second)` it gives deadlock. This steps involve manual and hard coded. How can we solve this issue?

Comment: Ha, that's a good spot on the subscription. This happens because every task starts asynchronously in `go task.Run(wg.Done)`. So there is a race condition and the task doesn't subscribe "fast" enough and misses the signaling. 

So you need to subscribe on the start ( show interested on listening the broadcast ). A corrected example https://go.dev/play/p/9SIK3mw4qU0.